# Why does the iPhone 4S weigh more than the iPhone 4?

Tags: hardware, iphone

It's been commonly noted that the iPhone 4S looks the same, but that its internals have been upgraded. Despite that, the iPhone 4S weighs more.

What causes the added weight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because *internal* hardware has been upgraded, this does not mean that the phone will not weigh more.

After all, *upgraded* hardware is *different* hardware.

Still, if that is not sufficient to you take a look at the teardown of the two phones. You will see that the internal design differs, which can cause weight difference.

- [teardown iPhone 4](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone-4-Teardown/3130/4)
- [teardown iPhone 4s](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone-4S-Teardown/6610/3)

Comment: 2 things to bear in mind.  Each gen of chips is manufactured smaller than the last.  Also, any spare space created by shrinking the chippery etc will be gobbled up by a bigger battery.  The single biggest and heaviest part of the iPhone 4 ($ derivatives, CDMA, 4S, etc) is that big 'ol battery.  Same goes for iPad.